# Full page vexflow render of song tablature

Tags: vexflow

I have been looking at vextab and vexflow and I am struggling to get beyond rendering a few notes, my aim is to render a full tab for a song.

When I add more notes they get truncated. I have looked at a number of examples but they all show a small number of notes.

Do I need to render each 'line of notes' separately or can I get vex to do this for me.

Apologies I am not a musician so my terminology is probably not correct.

I have tried changing the size of the div in which i have placed the vexTab not luck there.

Also I have looked at the canvas worker examples, I have got them working bu I cannot see how I can change the rendering to display multiple lines of TAB.